# Docker Trust - use own keys instead of auto-generated ones?

Tags: docker

We want to use our own RSA keys (foremost as root key and targets key) instead of using auto-generated ECDSa keys. How to do that?

All tooling seems to auto-generate ECDSa keys for us. Is there a command line argument we've not seen yet?

Comment: Along these lines (considering the DCT/Notary signing model) what benefits are there to using CA-signed delegate keys instead of the self-signed ones generated by `docker trust ...`?

Comment: In most public key systems there is a one key per device. Docker seems to prefer one key per repository. It would be helpful to re-use a secret key on a smartcard or yubikey for signing the images.

Comment: We want to use a specific key which we already have instead of a generated one. (Not doing key reuse, but it's complicated...it results in "we want to use a key instead of auto-generating one")